# Can I supply my own REST API token to the ArcGIS Javascrpit API?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-portal

I am using the ArcGIS Javascript API to connect to the arcgis.com portal. To do so I am calling `portal.signIn()`. The issue is that I don't want the user to be responsible for performing the login, bo I want to generate the REST API token on my server and then use that token from the Javascript API.

**Mock code**

```
portal = new esri.arcgis.Portal('http://www.arcgis.com');
dojo.connect(portal, 'onLoad', function() {
    portal.id.token="<server-side writes token here>";
    portal.signIn().then(function(loggedInUser){
        console.log(loggedInUser);
    });
});
```

EDIT:

From what I can tell in this sample http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/widget_identitymanager_client_side.html

I might be able to build my own credentials object to run esri.id.initialize() (which from what I understand is an implementation of esri.IdentityManager).  I will try this and report back if it works.

Comment: You can hard code a 'Long-lived' Token into your script http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_ArcGIS_tokens/0154000005r6000000/ but must use the token service of arcgis server to generate it.